# Switch multidimensional array key for value from within array

Tags: php

I have the following multidimensional array, returned from a query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dimension] => string
            [value_1] => 100
            [value_2] => 200
        )
```

What I'm looking to do is create this format instead, so I can access data within it by writing something like `$data['dimension']['key']`:

```
Array
(
    [string] => Array
        (
            [dimension] => string
            [value_1] => 100
            [value_2] => 200
        )
```

Is there a clean way to do this, or should I start playing with loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I know how to do it would be with a loop.

```
$new = Array();
foreach($old as $key => $value) {
    $new[$value['dimension']] = $value;
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Thanks, FDL. Most of my code looks like this and I'm trying to make the jump to 'smarter' programming, so I figured I'd ask. I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

You can create new array by combining keys and values:

`array_combine(array_column($array, 'dimension'), $array)`

But remember that the *dimension* have to be unique.

Comment: Work perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

you could access the data within as it is now, without more array modification by using this:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
//in case you want to view data in the arrays
//echo "Index array\n";
//print_r($index);
//echo "\nVals array\n";
//print_r($vals);

$answer = $vals[0][value_1];
echo $answer;
```

it should = 100